# out of 17 Task work items 15 are coming and 2 Task are not migrate

Tags: azure-devops-migration-tools

I have used the version of 10.2 and facing one of the issue following

****Issue is that out of 17 Task work items 15 are coming and 2 Task are not  migrated but in that place two  Product backlog item created with no title and state is coming with new state****

1. Here is my config file:

```json
{   "Version": "10.2",  
    "TelemetryEnableTrace": false,
    "workaroundForQuerySOAPBugEnabled": false,
    "ChangeSetMappingFile": null,
    "Source": {
        "Collection": "",
        "Project": "Road To NPD 3.0",
        "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "PATTInitiativesRefID",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
        "PersonalAccessToken": "",
        "LanguageMaps": {
          "AreaPath": "Road To NPD 3.0",
          "IterationPath": "Road To NPD 3.0"
        }   },   "Target": {
        "Collection": "",
        "Project": "AS-Scrum-RoadToNPD3.0",
        "ReflectedWorkItemIDFieldName": "AutoSolScrumRefID",
        "AllowCrossProjectLinking": false,
        "PersonalAccessToken": "",
        "LanguageMaps": {
          "AreaPath": "AS-Scrum-RoadToNPD3.0",
          "IterationPath": "AS-Scrum-RoadToNPD3.0"    }   },   "FieldMaps": [
        {
          "ObjectType": "MultiValueConditionalMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceFieldsAndValues": {
            "Field1": "Value1",
            "Field2": "Value2"
          },
          "targetFieldsAndValues": {
            "Field1": "Value1",
            "Field2": "Value2"
          }
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldBlankMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "targetField": "TfsMigrationTool.ReflectedWorkItemId"
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldValueMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceField": "System.State",
          "targetField": "System.State",
          "defaultValue": "New",
          //"valueMapping": {
           // "Approved": "New",
            //"New": "New",
            //"Committed": "Active",
            //"In Progress": "Active",
            //"To Do": "New",
            //"Done": "Closed",
            //"Removed": "Removed"
          //}
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldtoFieldMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.BacklogPriority",
          "targetField": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.StackRank",
          "defaultValue": null
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldtoFieldMultiMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "SourceToTargetMappings": {
            "SourceField1": "TargetField1",
            "SourceField2": "TargetField2"
          }
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldtoTagMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceField": "System.State",
          "formatExpression": "ScrumState:{0}"
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldMergeMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceField1": "System.Description",
          "sourceField2": "Microsoft.VSTS.Common.AcceptanceCriteria",
          "targetField": "System.Description",
          "formatExpression": "{0} <br/><br/><h3>Acceptance Criteria</h3>{1}",
          "doneMatch": "##DONE##"
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "RegexFieldMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceField": "COMPANY.PRODUCT.Release",
          "targetField": "COMPANY.DEVISION.MinorReleaseVersion",
          "pattern": "PRODUCT \\d{4}.(\\d{1})",
          "replacement": "$1"
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "FieldValuetoTagMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "sourceField": "Microsoft.VSTS.CMMI.Blocked",
          "pattern": "Yes",
          "formatExpression": "{0}"
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "TreeToTagMapConfig",
          "WorkItemTypeName": "*",
          "toSkip": 3,
          "timeTravel": 1    
        }   ],   "WorkItemTypeDefinition": {
        "Product Backlog Item": "Product Backlog Item",     "Epic": "Epic",     "Task": "Task"     },   "GitRepoMapping": null,   "Processors": [
        {
          "ObjectType": "NodeStructuresMigrationConfig",
          "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
          "Enabled": false,
          "BasePaths": [
           "Product\\Area\\Path1",
          "Product\\Area\\Path2"
          ]
        },
        {
          "ObjectType": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
          "ReplayRevisions": true,
          "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
          "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
          "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
          "BuildFieldTable": false,
          "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
          "QueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] != '' AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Task')",
          "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
          "Enabled": true,
          "LinkMigration": true,
          "AttachmentMigration": true,
          "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
          "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
          "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": false,
          "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
          "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
          "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
          "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
          "CollapseRevisions": false,
          "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false
        }   ] }
```

Comment: I updated the answer below, which should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is due to some code malfunctioning that is responsible for changing the work item type which is not possible in the old Object Model. Some folks have had issues with it, and so there is `SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType` that can be added to look at the type of the last revision and use that rather than trying to mess around in between.

```
{
          "ObjectType": "WorkItemMigrationConfig",
          "ReplayRevisions": true,
          "PrefixProjectToNodes": false,
          "UpdateCreatedDate": true,
          "UpdateCreatedBy": true,
          "BuildFieldTable": false,
          "AppendMigrationToolSignatureFooter": false,
          "QueryBit": "AND  [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate] != '' AND [System.WorkItemType] IN ('Task')",
          "OrderBit": "[System.ChangedDate] desc",
          "Enabled": true,
          "LinkMigration": true,
          "AttachmentMigration": true,
          "AttachmentWorkingPath": "c:\\temp\\WorkItemAttachmentWorkingFolder\\",
          "FixHtmlAttachmentLinks": false,
          "SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType": true,
          "WorkItemCreateRetryLimit": 5,
          "FilterWorkItemsThatAlreadyExistInTarget": true,
          "PauseAfterEachWorkItem": false,
          "AttachmentMazSize": 480000000,
          "CollapseRevisions": false,
          "LinkMigrationSaveEachAsAdded": false
        }   ] }
```

Here I updated `"SkipToFinalRevisedWorkItemType"` to be `true` instead of `false`.